# Most efficient language to implement tensor factorization for Web Application

Tags: python, c++, mysql, django, large-data

I have implemented Tensor Factorization Algorithm in Matlab. But, actually, I need to use it in Web Application.

So I implemented web site on Django framework, now I need to merge it with my Tensor Factorization algorithm.

For those who are not familiar with tensor factorization, you can think there are bunch of multiplication, addition and division on large matrices of size, for example 10 000 x 8 000. In tensor factorization case we do not have matrices, instead we have 3-dimensional(for my purpose) arrays.

By the way, I m using MySQL as my database.

I am considering to implement this algorithm in Python or in C++. But I can't be sure which one is better. 
Do you have any idea about efficiency of Python and C++ when processing on huge data set? Which one is better? Why?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172496)

Comment: Yes, you are right Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation "Engine", If it was, we were getting answers directly from genius Engine, not people that are proficient on particular subjects.

Comment: Yeah, you kinda missed the point. This question is not constructive for SO as per the FAQ and meta.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Django, you are using Python on your web site.  You should investigate SciPy/NumPy and see if they are suitable for your purposes.

http://scipy.org/

[Link](https://numpy.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Python is just fine. I am a Python person. I do not know C++ personally. However, during my research of python the creator of mathematica stated himself that python is equally as powerful as mathematica. Python is used in many highly accurate calculations. (i. e. engineering software, architecture work, etc. . .)